# where can i find any text formatting scripts like the one used in stackoverflow?

Tags: php, text, markdown

I want to give users the option to format text like bold, italic, add image etc ...

I want to give list of options as such as given here in stackoverflow while asking questions

Where can i find any predefined scripts for that? I searched  on google , but i think i haven't searched with a proper text and i couldn't find anything relevant!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Markdown for PHP is located at

- http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/

Alternatives to Markdown can be found at

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_markup_language

---

Somewhat related is this blog entry about what StackOverflow was built with:

- https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/

You'll find many more answers about SO on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 3):

Actually:

- **[Markdown](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/)** is used by SO
- [**Prettify**](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) is the code colorizer that StackOverflow uses.
- **[TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/)**/  **[WMD Editor](http://github.com/derobins/wmd)** (used by SO)

Answer (score 2):

SO uses the WMD editor, which you can find [here](http://github.com/derobins/wmd).  It also uses [MarkdownSharp](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/) to generate the HTML shown on the page.  You'd need to replace this with a PHP version of Markdown -- @Gordon's answer contains a link.

Answer (score 1):

What you are after is something to 'parse' the text.

This will be a special function that looks at a string such as `**my text**` and notices the pair of `*` before and after the string `my text` it then converts the first pair into a `<b>` and the second pair get turned into `</b>`.

You can either do it in JavaScript or server side code, either before or after you store/read from the data base.

There are lots of library's that other people have been mentioning. But if you wanted to do it your self, that is the basic principle.

Answer (score 0):

This are all editor.  So use any of the editor and customize your input option.